# Run Tomcat and deploy project with own server.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I just want to run a web project that has been configured in a maven project with the pom.xml.
It uses the maven tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy the web app artifact and all is working properly at this point.

Now I want to add its own server.xml and tomcat-users.xml in the tomcat configuration. I read that I need to add the following lines.

```
 <serverXml>src/main/resources/tomcat/server.xml</serverXml>
 <tomcatUsers>src/main/resources/tomcat/tomcat-users.xml</tomcatUsers>
```

And that is fine. It is working now and tomcat is deployed using the configuration file above,but the problem is > **Web application artifact is not deployed there** (is not deployed automatically when I run tomcat7:run). It seems the artifact is not detected by the plugin and just starts the tomcat server without adding the artifact to the webapps just use the new config files.

I use this config.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
           <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/web-services</url>
        <path>/web-services</path>
        <serverXml>src/main/resources/tomcat/server.xml</serverXml>
                <tomcatUsers>src/main/resources/tomcat/tomcat-users.xml</tomcatUsers>
                   <warRunDependencies>
                    <warRunDependency>
                     <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.koitoer.webservices</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web-services</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>war</type>
                      </dependency>
                    <contextPath>/web-services</contextPath>
                </warRunDependency>
              </warRunDependencies>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

But tomcat starts deploy the webapp artifact but does not use the new config files.

What is the correct configuration there, I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604377/tomcat7-maven-plugin-custom-server-xml) but nothing, this is possible or I should add the war file manually using tomcat manager?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this issue?

Comment: Sorry weekend was too busy , today I will review and let you know

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [tomcat7-maven-plugin documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml) says for `<serverXml>`:

> server.xml to use **Note if you use this you must configure in this file
>   your webapp paths.**

I think this means that you have to insert a `<Context>` element with the path of your war inside the `<Host>` element, like so:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployXML="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context docBase="../../webapp" path="/webapp" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

Where "webapp" is my generated war name. Apparently, `appBase` is relative to `target/tomcat` (and "webapps" seems to be the default value). `docBase` is relative to `appBase` so for simplicity I used the relative path to the build directory.

This is working for me, and without that `<Context>` element I get a white page.

If you are using filtering you can probably replace `docBase` by a property. However take care to exclude the server.xml (and tomcat-users.xml) from your war file!

Comment: thanks @Didier L, you point me in the right direction it seems tha tomcat now is taking the context file and load the war file on the fly, sorry for the late answer and as you was the first to answer I give you the bounty, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I have added the following into **server.xml** and my application is working fine with tomcat7:run-war command:

```xml
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployXML="false"
    name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context docBase="../../webApplicationName"
        path="/webApplicationName" reloadable="true" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
        directory="logs"
        prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Here is how I configure plug-in in **pom.xml**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>

    <configuration> 
        <path>/</path>
        <serverXml>src/main/tomcatconf/server.xml</serverXml>
        <warDirectory>target/appName</warDirectory>
        <webapps> 
            <webapp> 
                <groupId>com.abc</groupId> 
                <artifactId>appName</artifactId> 
                <version>7.0.1</version> 
                <type>war</type>    
            </webapp> 
        </webapps> 
    </configuration>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
</plugin>
```

I have dropped `server.xml` + other config files into `src/main/tomcatconf` directory (default value of plugin) and also have `context.xml` into `META-INF` dir and into `src/main/tomcatconf`. The plugin seems to be picking up `context.xml` from one of the directories.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Very good explanation my friend but Didier answer before of you with a very similar comment, thanks a lot for showing us and share your pom. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this configuration

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <finalName>servidor-identidades-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>myserver</server>
          <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
          <path>/servidor-identidades-webapp</path>
          <warSourceDirectory>C:/Users/fulanis/workspace2/web/target/servidor-identidades-webapp.jar</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Ref:
 https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+create+a+Maven+web+app+and+deploy+to+Tomcat+-+fast

Hope this helps.