# Where the tomcat location when running application with broadleaf

Tags: java, tomcat7, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to run a simple demo application of broadleaf. I am perfectly running the app, but I want to access it using any PC except this. I have to change some settings in tomcat but I am not able to find where tomcat is located and where the server.xml file located so I can do any kind of changes in server in order to make it running on any PC using public IP.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Broadleaf (broadleaf-4.0.0-GA) uses `tomcat7-maven-plugin` for the demo site, which will run a embedded tomcat instance. If you need a custom `server.xml` please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101945/run-tomcat-and-deploy-project-with-own-server-xml/).

You can find tomcat-maven config in pom.xml of **site** project.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <port>${httpPort}</port>
                <httpsPort>${httpsPort}</httpsPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Update this with required changes from the link above.

Comment: that is ok about server.xml. Now I want it to access as public ip but I am not able to access the same. What are the changes to be maid in this to make it accessible using public ip

Comment: by public IP do you mean, access it over internet (from anywhere)? Or you just want to access it in over your LAN (office/home network)?

Comment: I need to run it on mysql but it gives exceptions  addResource
[artifact:mvn] WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver I have followed all kind of steps for setting it up