# OpenShift Migration - What To Do About .openshift Folder?

Tags: tomcat, migration, openshift, redhat

There are many companies/people migrating their **OpenShift v2** applications to **OpenShift Pro** due to the imminent sunset of OpenShift 2.

The OpenShift v2 folder **.openshift** no longer features in **OpenShift Pro** and RedHat's migration documentation actually states it should be **removed**.

But what if you have actually used a feature exposed by .openshift such as Tomcat settings? For example **tomcat-users.xml** or **server.xml**.

I, myself have used **server.xml** to specify an addition **docBase**.

```
<Context docBase="${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/documents" path="/documents" />
```

**What am I to do?**

**How is this achieved in OpenShift Pro?**

**Is it no longer possible to do?**

**Is it frowned upon?**

Now we are **paying customers**, perhaps someone at **RedHat** (or elsewhere) could enlighten us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [document](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/using_images/xpaas_images/jws.html) has the answer (not tried):

> 2. All WAR files from the deployments source repository directory are copied to /opt/webserver/webapps.
> 3. All files in the configuration source repository directory are copied to /opt/webserver/conf.
>
> If you want to use custom Tomcat configuration files, the file names
>   should be the same as for a normal Tomcat installation. For example,
>   context.xml and server.xml.

Try logging to pod shell via `oc rhc <pod_id>` and explore `/opt/webserver/conf` area.

### **EDIT 1 -**

With each deployment, the server is rebuilt and changes to server.xml would be lost. So, all the config files should be part of the repo from which the image is created.

If you are using maven build and would like a cutom deployment of config file like server.xml, check [this article](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml)

Sample POM [given here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/maven-plugin/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/src/test/resources/deploy-war-project/pom.xml).

**EDIT 2**

Another simpler approach suggested by @Lyndon in the comments

> All you need to do is create a folder called configuration under the
>   top level git folder. Any file you put in there will get copied to:
>   /opt/webserver/conf. It really is that simple.

Comment: Thanks gyan but when I added the docBase line to server.xml in the /opt/webserver/conf folder, the file was overwritten and the change lost in the subsequent deployment. I will recheck that that was what happened...

Comment: I believe, you should deploy this via repo/git. I mean checkin your server.xml to repo and let the build process take care of deployment. Because each deployment is similar to rebuilding a fresh server from scratch, any config changes has to come via a repo.

Comment: That's how it used to work but from the .openshift folder. That;s no longer used. Where exactly would I put my server.xml file now? It exists in tomcat/conf folder not in git. This should be easy (like it used to be)...

Comment: Added more details. You should look here to see how it is done using maven - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101945/run-tomcat-and-deploy-project-with-own-server-xml

Comment: You got me onto the right path but it is much simpler than was suggested by those articles. All you need to do is create a folder called configuration under the top level git folder. Any file you put in there will get copied to: /opt/webserver/conf. It really is that simple...

Comment: Sadly, although this method does indeed deploy the server.xml, the deployment of the pod fails with this: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/deployments/${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/documents] is not valid
- For some strange reason '/deployments' has been added to the path. This will become a new question tomorrow...

Comment: Try to set environment variable through .s2i/bin/run just before execution. Please check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466516/openshift-migration-env-variables-in-conf-file-not-replaced-as-before