# Maven tomcat7 exec-war-only Error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I want to create an executable war/jar like explained in the tomcat7-maven-plugin documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/executable-war-jar.html

But i get a build failure (NullPointerException):

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Gothic Mod Manager 0.1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war (default-cli) @ gmm >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gmm ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gmm ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ gmm ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gmm ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ gmm ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ gmm ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [gmm] in [C:\***\GMM\target\gmm-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\***\GMM\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [963 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\***\GMM\target\gmm-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war-only (executable) @ gmm ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war (default-cli) @ gmm <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war (default-cli) @ gmm ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.854s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 09 18:55:09 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war (default-cli) on project gmm: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war (default-cli) on project gmm: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:exec-war failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractExecWarMojo.execute(AbstractExecWarMojo.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

The goals **tomcat7:deploy**, **:redeploy**, **:undeploy** and the startup of a local embedded server with **tomcat7:run** work as expected.

Unlike the documentation i linked above i only have a single .pom file, so i merged the parts from the docu together. My pom now looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.gothic-reloaded-mod</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmm</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Gothic Mod Manager</name>
    <url>https://github.com/Katharsas/GMM</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.52</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/GMM</path>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>**********</password>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>executable</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                            <goal>exec-war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>

                            <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>

                            <warRunDependencies>
                                <warRunDependency>
                                    <dependency>
                                        <groupId>de.gothic-reloaded-mod</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>gmm</artifactId>
                                        <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                        <type>war</type>
                                    </dependency>
                                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                                </warRunDependency>
                            </warRunDependencies>

                            <extraDependencies>
                                <extraDependency>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                                    <version>10.1.3.1</version>
                                </extraDependency>
                                <extraDependency>
                                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.4</version>
                                </extraDependency>
                            </extraDependencies>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Additional info: Im using Eclipse Kepler, my Run Configuration looks like this:
**tomcat7:exec-war -e**
I also tried with the commando line, tried **:exec-war-only** but nothing worked.

I searched and tried different things for days now, so any help is much appreciated! : ]

Comment: When I had same issue I have fixed as I posted in this link
[Tomcat7 maven executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604377/tomcat7-maven-plugin-custom-server-xml/56577478#56577478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar issue with version 2.2 of the plugin, but I got it run with 2.1 according to [this tutorial](http://ufasoli.blogspot.de/2013/11/create-runnable-war-with-embedded.html?q=runnable+war).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works flawless for me, without any config struggling!

Answer (score 3):

The NPE is because the plugin does not find the packaged war file, I fixed that error by explicitly adding the `package` phase to the build, so for example:

```
mvn clean package tomcat7:exec-war
```

any phase that produce the war package fits well for avoiding the NPE: package, install, deploy, etc.

So, in your case, where you use a Run Configuration in Eclipse, just add `package` before `tomcat7:exec-war -e`

Answer (score 2):

There is a version 2.3 now where the problem from 2.2 has been fixed!

(had some problems with 2.1 because it is so old)

Sadly its only a snapshot version and needs to be fetched from Apache Snapshots Repository. To get it you need to put this into your pom:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Then you can use the new [version](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/dependency-info.html) `<version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Comment: I don't see a 2.3 available. Never released? :(

Comment: It is released at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin/
It's not on maven central, thats why you need to add the code from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error with spring boot application. I had to spend quite sometime so putting it here that below plugin needs to be included

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

Also packaging type should be jar

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Start-class should be defined as your main class

```
<start-class>com.edu.schoolT.SchoolWeb</start-class>
```

main class or class annotated with @SpringBootApplication should extend SpringBootServletInitializer. For further info...
[Create a deployable war file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed similar issue in my project and given reference below link

[tomcat7-maven-plugin custom server.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604377/tomcat7-maven-plugin-custom-server-xml/56577478#56577478)

Find pom.xml changes for this issue